# Opening links in webview from other methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am completely new to iOS development so please don't assume anything about my expertise in this area.

I successfully implemented a webview in my project and assigned it a url to load in the 'viewDidLoad' method. This works fine. When I try loading an url from within the 'handleOpenURL' method in AppDelegate nothing happens because the referenced webview is nil.

ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController ()
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)requesturl {
    // handler code here
    return YES;
}
```

My question is: how do I target the webview from within other methods?

Answer (score 0):

This method is to "Asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL"

not to open the URL like google or lod a page

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom URL scheme, like if you are integrating iOS with Facebook SDK, then you will use this method, not to open google or any other url in webview. Its not necessary that you can load in only viewDidLoad method, you can load url in webview in any other method of your viewcontroller

Comment: Hi Bhanu, I am using a url scheme to reopen the app. Reopening the app works fine. The entrypoint is 'handleOpenURL' but I can't load an url in the webview from there because the webview is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the url in `application:handleOpenURL:` in your AppDelegate and then in `application:handleOpenURL:` init and open the ViewController

Comment: Hi Bogren, I can get the url in handleOpenURL. I do not understand the bit  '..in handleOpenURL: init and open the ViewController..' Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: What you probably want to do is to init your Viewcontroller and show it? Is your Viewcontroller present when you re:open the app, then you can pass the url to the viewcontroller by fetching the controller from the view hierarchy. 


Note; there is probably going to be different cases. 1. when the viewcontroller is not present and you need to initialize and present it 2. When it's present and only need to pass the url 3. when it's initialized but not present, then I suggest you reset the stack to root viewcontroller then present your Viewcontroller and pass the url.

Comment: Yes, it is present. I can call a method on it. From that method I tried to target the webview but it was nil. I think that I need to say somewhere: 'This is the webview you must target' but I don't know how.

Comment: Sounds like your webview is not initilized properly, is it set up in storyboard/IB?